# SQL, count days with occurences of several modules

Tags: mysql, datetime, group-by, count

I'm having data that shows occurrences A and B at a certain timestamp for several different modules, here's a dummy table (sorry for the layout, really can't find out how to do this properly):

```
-------------------------------------------
|Timestamp  |    Occurrence   |  Module  |

2018-01-29 11:03:31  | A      |       M1

2018-01-29 15:23:38  | A      |       M1

2018-01-29 17:10:10  |  B     |       M1

2018-01-29 20:49:47  |  B     |     M2

2018-01-29 21:01:11   | A     |   M2

-

2018-01-30 02:32:16   | A     |       M1

2018-01-30 04:59:47  |  B     |       M2

-

2018-01-31 03:18:25  |  B     |        M2

2018-01-31 07:26:55 |   A     |       M2

2018-01-31 09:01:01  |  A     |         M1

2018-01-31 11:41:33  |  B     |         M2

2018-01-31 14:58:42  |  B      |        M2
```

What I want is for all modules to count the number of days that at least 1 occurrence is logged, and count this for occurrence A and B, so that for the dummy table the following result would appear:

```
Module  | Occurence_A | Occurence_B

_ M1 _    |   _____ 3 ____      |     ____1____

_ M2 _    |   _____2_____      |      ____3____
```

I tried several GROUP BY and SELECT COUNT statements but I can't seem to figure it out. Anyone that can help?

Comment: Will the occurrence have values A and B only?

Comment: They can also have other values but I only want to look at A and B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GROUP BY Module and count the distinct dates of the occurrences:

```
SELECT Module,
   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Occurrence = 'A' THEN DATE(Timestamp) END) AS Occurrence_A,
   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN Occurrence = 'B' THEN DATE(Timestamp) END) AS Occurrence_B
FROM tablename
WHERE Occurrence IN ('A', 'B')
GROUP BY Module
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/b8cyDjkg2xe5G83hxaNasE/0).
Results:

```
| Module | Occurrence_A | Occurrence_B |
| ------ | ------------ | ------------ |
| M1     | 3            | 1            |
| M2     | 2            | 3            |
```

Comment: Thank you! I will check and try to implement it tomorrow but I trust it works

Comment: Amazing! Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!